# Revive Adserver and Geotargeting by City with GeoLiteCity.dat

Tags: openx, maxmind, banner-ads, advertisement-server, geotargetting

I'm trying to set up Geo Targeting for my Revive adserver, but have one question.

I'm using the GeoLite City and GeoLite Country files from Maxmind (the .dat files) and have uploaded them to my server and added them in the Maxmind plugin settings.

So far so good, but:

When I try to Geo Target a banner by City, I first get to choose the country in a drop down list, but then there is only a text field where I add the cities.

Is this the intended behaviour? I thought that there would be a drop down for the cities as well? Or should I write the cities manually? What if there are different ways of spelling a city name for instance?

Any hints?

Comment: One off-topic question: Where did you get the `.DAT` files? I can't find them in MaxMind website and the `.CSV` and `.MMDB` files don't work on Revive AdServer. Do you know any articles that can help me start off with the GeoTargeting? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, got it working, now in the same situation as you!